# MacBook Pro Cursor Lag

Tags: mac, mouse, macbook-pro, mouse-cursor

I am on a 2019 MacBook Pro running Big Sur, but this problem has carried over from previous updates. Basically, my cursor lags every two seconds or so for about a quarter second, at a consistent timing. It does not matter if I am using the trackpad or a usb connected mouse, the lag is present. I have tried checking whether I am using too much memory or CPU, and I am not - nothing else has lag or delay  when this issue is occurring. Interestingly, I have had it go away at random times for a bit, and then return. When it first popped up, I did a full reset of my computer and it did not go away (I cleared the disk of everything, including the OS and re-downloaded from ICloud).

I have tried everything that I can think of, and am still stuck. Does anyone have any more advice?

Comment: Hello!  You can always put that as an answer and mark it as the answer.  It's the proper format for self-answered questions :).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just figured out the issue for anyone else with a similar issue. I have a second monitor that I connect with a USB-C to HDMI connection, but at times the monitor does not connect to the laptop despite being plugged in correctly (I suspect a faulty adapter). This issue occurs when the monitor is supposedly connected manually, but not connecting well enough to display anything, and is fixed either by not trying to connect to the monitor, or by connecting properly.